# rename file retrieved from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to rename a file in my android before encrypting and uploading it (my app encrypts and uploads files)

The permissions are already written in my manifest file
so i retrieve the file from the intent and i try to rename it but i keep getting a false, this is my code : 
can anyone please help? thanks

```
public void renameFilebeforeUpload(final Intent data)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage("Voulez vous renommer votre fichier?")
            .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String name =  data.getData().getPath();
                    BsSdkLog.d("name of the file: "+name);
                    BsSdkLog.d("what is this?: "+data.getData().toString());
                    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File savesFile = new File(sdcard,data.getData().getPath());
                    File newFile = new File(sdcard,"hello");
                    Boolean b=savesFile.renameTo(newFile);
                    BsSdkLog.d("file renamed"+b);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mItemManager.encryptAndUploadFile(data.getData(), mHomeViewModel.getPath(),true);
                }
            })
            .show();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,final  Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               BsSdkLog.d("result is ok");
               renameFilebeforeUpload(data);

            }
            break;
        case FILE_PICKER2:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                mItemManager.encryptAndUploadFile(data.getData(), mHomeViewModel.getPath(),false);
            }
            break;

    }
}


public void pickUploadFile(boolean pickfile) {
    if (StringFormatter.isSharePath(mHomeViewModel.getPath())) {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), "Impossible dans un dossier partagé", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choisissez un fichier"),
                HomeFragment.FILE_PICKER);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Snackbar.make(mRootView, "Vous devez installer un gestionnaire de fichiers.",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

my getPath method :

```
  getPath method taken entirely from HomePoint code base
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        CustomLog.getInstance().d(" File -" +
                "Authority: " + uri.getAuthority() +
                        ", Fragment: " + uri.getFragment() +
                        ", Port: " + uri.getPort() +
                        ", Query: " + uri.getQuery() +
                        ", Scheme: " + uri.getScheme() +
                        ", Host: " + uri.getHost() +
                        ", Segments: " + uri.getPathSegments().toString()
        );

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your `startActivityForResult()` calls that are triggering your `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: i've edited my question

Answer (score 2):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not a "file picker" `Intent` action. The user picks a piece of content, and the `Uri` that you get back should have a `content` scheme and point to that piece of content. **This is not a file**, and you cannot rename it, any more than you can rename this Web page via its `Uri` (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999477/rename-file-retrieved-from-intent`).

Also, `data.getData().getPath()` will not work with a `content` scheme.

I do not know what `encryptAndUploadFile()` does. It should be using a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` (works for `content` and `file` schemes).

Comment: the method getPath does all that , this is why i'm calling it .

Comment: @apps: "the method getPath does all that" -- I do not know what you consider "all that" to be. For a `content` `Uri`, `getPath()` is meaningless. If you only want files, get rid of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and use [a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created). You will not be able to get at all of the user's content (removable storage, Google Drive, etc.), but at least you will be working with files.

Comment: i can't get rid of the action get content because i need the Uri, it's through this uri that i am doing my encryption.

Comment: @apps: Then stop using `getPath()` and stop trying to rename the user's content. Or, get rid of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, use a file chooser library, and use `Uri.fromFile()` to get a `Uri` for the rest of your code.